# I have to got to Spain and have lost my passport. What do I do?

Tags: international-travel, spain

I have flight for 5 June for Spain and I've lost my passport and it's first time visa. Please give me information what i do?

Comment: Make a police report, get a new passport, and go back to whichever embassy you got the visa from and apply for a new visa. Carry the police report along and possibly a photocopy of the old visa and passport details page. You may also want to notify the embassy asap even before getting the new passport so they cancel the visa before some criminal may use it.

Comment: What country issued your passport, and where are you now?

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie, this should be an answer.

Comment: ...and once you've reported it gone, don't use it even if you find it again.

Comment: @joernano It appears pretty obvious to most what the OP was asking.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie phoog's questions are valid and still require answering. Hence it is unclear.

Answer (score 19):

Report the theft/loss to the police and get a police report. Immediately notify the issuing embassy so they cancel/void the visa before some criminal may use it and cause complications for you via identity theft. Reporting to the police promptly helps convince the issuing embassy that the loss is genuine so there won't be suspicion you're part of a passport/visa racket.

Apply for a new passport, then return to whichever embassy you got the visa from and apply for a new visa. Remember to carry the police report along and possibly a photocopy of the old visa and passport details page when going for your interview.

Finally have on you all documents (e.g bank statements, employment letter etc) needed just like you would if applying for a new visa. Some countries don't just replace a missing visa, they evaluate you all over again like a fresh application.

Comment: Why report the police? I thought that informing the embassy is enough.

Comment: @BЈовић So that the police know to not come after them if someone successfully uses their visa for identity fraud.

Comment: Or if someone commits a crime and shows that passport as their ID.

Comment: @BЈовић the police report may be necessary to get a replacement.