# I lost Indian passport with US multi-entry visa valid until April 2021

Tags: indian-citizens, legal, lost-documents

I got this passport at the Bengaluru passport office and American visa at Mount Road in Chennai.

There is no scanned copy available. I do not remember even the number, but I travelled twice to the USA, in June 2011 and July 2016.

I need a duplicate issued urgently with the US visa to go to the US the first week of June 2017 to attend my niece's wedding on June 19 in Bridgewater, New Jersey.

Comment: There is nothing that anyone on this site can do. You have to replace your passport with the Indian authorities directly, and, unfortunately, must apply for a new visa at the US Consulate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have to got to Spain and have lost my passport. What do I do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93333/i-have-to-got-to-spain-and-have-lost-my-passport-what-do-i-do)

Comment: Hey, VTC for being a duplicate of a question that has been closed as "unclear what you are asking" makes no sense at all. Unless you mean that both question are duplicate-ly unclear :-D

Comment: But what's your _question_?

Comment: @motoDrizzt I agree that it makes no sense. Even if the other question was still open, this wouldn't be a duplicate of it, since it's entirely possible that the USA and Spain have different policies about visas in lost passports. However, this "question" certainly is unclear: there's no question at all, so I'm voting to close for that reason.

Comment: @DavidRicherby yep, I see no question too :-D

Answer (score 4):

Googling [lost visa site:https://in.usembassy.gov](https://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBCA742CA742&biw=1061&bih=606&q=lost+visa+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fin.usembassy.gov&oq=lost+visa+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fin.usembassy.gov&gs_l=serp.3...12685.14125.0.14752.8.8.0.0.0.0.149.682.5j3.8.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.5.397...0j0i7i30k1j0i8i30k1j0i22i30k1j33i21k1.9g536Q90IRw) immediately finds the relevant page which has this to say about [Lost or Stolen Passport or Visa](https://in.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/frequently-asked-questions-niv/#nivfaqs5):

You must report the loss of your passport and visa to the local Indian Police and obtain a police report. Please report the loss of the visa to the Fraud Prevention Unit at: support-india@ustraveldocs.com.

1. Your name, date and place of birth, and nationality.
2. Your address and phone number.
3. A photocopy of the lost visa, if available, or the date and place of issuance, if known.
4. A photocopy of the bio-data page of your lost passport, if available.  If not, the nationality and number of your lost passport as well as the issuance and expiration dates, if available.
5. Circumstances of the loss: When and how your passport was lost or stolen.

Lost or stolen U.S. visas cannot be replaced. For replacement of a visa, you must apply in person at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate. When applying for the replacement of a visa, you will need to explain the loss of your passport and visa.

If you have already reported your visa lost/stolen to the U.S. Embassy or Consulate, and then you later find your misplaced visa, please note that the visas will be invalid for future travel to the U.S. You must apply in person at the Embassy or Consulate for a new visa.

---

Also note that the [Apply for an Expedited Appointment](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-niv-expeditedappointment.asp) page explicitly says "Travel for the purpose of attending weddings [...] does not qualify for expedited appointments". It does not mention reissuing visas at all so it is not exactly known whether you'd qualify but since it lists the legit reasons for an expedited appointment, my opinion -- and I am just a random stranger on the Internet -- is that you don't. Other embassy pages on the same topic with slightly different wording for eg the [London](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/lost-and-stolen-passports/) one says "An appointment for an interview may be scheduled online at" and surely it would mention if expedited appointments are available for this purpose. Cancel your travel and beg the airline to refund your ticket. There's nothing you can do. Sorry. Maybe this sounds cruel but I do empathize with you, my nephew is the only light in my life and he also lives an ocean away and I'd be absolutely heartbroken if I couldn't attend such an important event so yes, I fully understand your situation but, alas, it seems there is nothing you can do :(